# Is it possible to get All IP's that belongs to given zip code?

Tags: network, ip, tcp, udp

For this kind of things can use Country IP blocker , but it only gives whole country IP's, so what im asking is , Is there any way to get All IP's that belongs to given Zip code?

Comment: You're going to get a lot of false positives/negatives for anything that fine grained.  My IP address gets detected as Everett, which is about 30 minutes from where I actually live.  Which has 4 physical-address zipcodes.  Remember, service providers are **NOT** required to give out the mapping, never mind the fact that most of them are probably using NAT for consumers.  Country-level restrictions only work because countries have specific ranges assigned.  What are you trying to do here?  And what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: Countries don't have IP ranges assigned but ISP and companies have. And there are lots of errors in the various GEO databases so even the country can be wrong.

Comment: piwik has a cities DB, which is finer than country, but it's not down to zip...

Comment: i see ,  those are makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The only valid ways to do that are:

- Request it from the provider
- Buy the list from the black market

If you're asking if you can find this by some type of GGE-like databases: no, they are often quite inaccurate.

Comment: got what you says.